# Mac Os X - Xcode4 and remote git-repository (and a local repository on the Mac)

Tags: xcode, git, macos, local

i am git/mac-newbie...

I coding with Xcode 4 and want now a remote git repository (for other persons and me).
I want the remote repository on my mac and a local copy too (like the local repository's on the other computers)

I started with creating a repository:
git init
git add .
.
.
.

and i think my problem is "make a remote repository".
the tutorials says i have to use this command:
git remote add remote ssh://git at git.petermac.com/usr/local/share/gitrepos/myprojectname].git
or
git remote add origin \
ssh://USERNAME@PROJECTNAME.git.sourceforge.net/gitroot/PROJECTNAME/REPONAME

But i dont want the repository on sourceforge. I want it on my machine.
I downt know how i adress my Mac over the network, or how i can reach it.
Is there something like "localhost" and need i ssh?

Comment: I found now this tutorial: http://blog.pkgbox.org/2009/12/setting-up-git-server-fast-macos-x.html

But i stuck at this command:
$ sudo /opt/local/libexec/git-core/git-daemon \
--base-path=/Library/WebServer/Documents \
--syslog --verbose \
--pid-file=/var/run/git-daemon.pid \
--user=_www --group=_www --detach

The terminal tells me: /opt/local/libexec/git-core/git-daemon command not found

Comment: problem solved: i found /libexec/git-core/git-daemon under /usr
/opt/local is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it depends on your installation of git as GIT is not included in the MacOS X distribution. I wrote the tutorial with a certain installation in mind. I will update it accordingly - so it matches to all kinds of git. Thanks for the info.

*updated* :-)

Please note - if you run MacOS X Lion client or server version with an updated XCode, git will be onboard already. I've rewritten the [tutorial (see this link)](http://blog.pkgbox.org/2011/07/setting-up-git-server-on-macos-x-lion.html) for the new changes with Lion.

Comment: And I wrote a little Python script to switch out the Xcode version with your own version if you chose a different install method for Git  https://gist.github.com/774277